# Double Space text on button from code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add text on a asp.net button depending on a virtual keyboard status

if the keyboard is visible the button text must be Hide Keyboard and if the Keyboard is not visible the text must be Show Keyboard. the button width is too short for the text i need to do a double space text inside the button i had already tried with

```
1-&#13;&#10;
2- </br>
3- /n
4-adding a literal br
```

and nothing works can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by saying "double space"?

Comment: Show the markup please. At least the one you want, both cases.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to define the button text?

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiline text in asp.net assign text in code begind. it's not pretty but it works well.

```
button.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2";
```